# Bash code for matching paths with patterns that may include wildcards

Tags: bash, wildcard

I'd like to know how does bash check for match between file paths and patterns that may contain the wildcard '*'.

I've looked in bash open source and downloaded from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) but couldn't figure out where is the engine that does this processing.. 
perhaps it can be found somewhere else ?

For Example, if i have the following directory tree:

```
~$ find 1
1
1/2
1/2/21
1/2/22
1/2/23
1/2/23/221
1/2/23/223
1/3
1/3/21
1/3/22
1/3/23
1/3/31
1/3/32
1/3/33
1/3/33/333
1/3/33/334
1/4
1/4/41
1/4/42
1/4/43
```

And I'd like to catch all files that are members of '1' and have content of '23'.

```
~$ find 1/*/23
1/2/23
1/2/23/221
1/2/23/223
1/3/23
```

Or find all members of 1/2:

```
~$ find 1/2
1/2
1/2/21
1/2/22
1/2/23
1/2/23/221
1/2/23/223
```

Comment: Are you interested in finding out how Bash works, or rather the `find` utility?

Comment: I thought bash itself process the pattern, and used 'find' command only to demonstrate how the pattern is processed (i could also use 'ls'). but maybe i'm wrong... i only want to see the source code of this matching.

Comment: `-regextype` option? I used this short ref http://ss64.com/bash/find.html

Comment: I actually want to see the source code, so that i can adopt something similar into my own project. I don't need regex, to keep it simple as possible.

Comment: Did you read [`man glob`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob)?

Comment: @unwind, thanks, seem like bash doesn't interpret these patterns directly, and it's done inside another process named `globbing` that know how to recognise and expand the wildcards .. I haven't found this process yet, but do you know where can i find it's source code ?

Comment: @unwind, I've found the desired engine in glob.c as you suggested, thanks a lot. it can be found in unix 6th edition source under /usr/source/s1/glob.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "globbing" and is handled by a GNU glibc library function:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching

Also see `glob(3)`, `glob(7)`, and `fnmatch(3)`.